# How to instantly check if GTM Tag created is tracked in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I created a custom metric in Google Analytics to track users who end up on that page.

This is the metric:

[image]

This is my setup in Google Tag Manager:

[image]

[image]

While I can see from GTM preview that the tag is firing, I don't understand why I don't see anything related to this in the Realtime -> Events (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMiaj.png).

[image]

Question 1: why does nothing show up? Do I have to wait until tomorrow for data to be populated in the reports view? If so, is there a way to instantly check whether the tag is tracked by GA? Having to wait 24 hours to know whether the tag is firing sounds abit long.

Question 2: Am I setting up my custom metric correctly? The intention is to track the error rate of users and be able to see which geographies / age range etc they come from.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/  or possibly https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the GTM tags in your screenshot are Pageview tags, so they wont show in the Real time > Events section. Check the Real time > Content report for your pageview being fired.
If you want to pass the metric with an Event, you need to create an Event tag and add the metric to the Event tag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried it out and it does not show me whether my tags are firing correctly (https://i.imgur.com/5cyNRVr.png). By right the tag should fire only if users land on a page ending with "error/?utm_source=checkout". I visited my website on two different browsers, one ending with "error/?utm_source=checkout" and the other without it. However as you can see from the screenshot, 2 views are found when it should only be one. May I know what is going on? Thank you.

Comment: change the parameter to test=checkout instead of utm_source=checkout and test it again. utm parameters wont usually show as part of a request URI unless appended via a # rather than a ?. Also not general good practice to use utm parameters in this way as it can bork your originating referral info up

Comment: Thanks for your help. Have tried out what you said and this is what I see: https://i.imgur.com/bp5T92Z.png. While there are now two different lines, I still don't understand how this proves whether my tag is firing properly. All this shows is that there are page views to two different links on my site. How do I check that my tag from GTM is indeed firing correctly and captured into Google Analytics as a custom metric? Thanks once again.

Comment: Use GA debugger and it should show what custom dimensions and/or metrics are being passed with the applicable pageview hit. You wont get custom dimensions or metric data in the real time reports and the data can take up to 24hrs to process into the standard reports. If you create a custom report you can apply your custom metric to that and if you apply the current days date to the report, once it does process (if in less than 24hrs) then you will see the data in your custom report.

Comment: GTM in preview mode will also show you what custom metrics are being passed with the applicable pageview hit.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will download it to try it out. Can I also check whether I am setting up my tag the right way? Or is there a better way to set it up to achieve what I want ie. get unique page views on error page divided by unique users. Right now I don't think the tag is tracking unique views on the error page and I am not sure how to set such a tag up.

Comment: I assuming you are not expecting users to land on the error page very often. I would track it as a goal. or you could create a segment based on users that end up with a pageview for that particular page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes you are right I don't expect many to land on that error page. However, I am also using the same method to track users who successfully land on another page after they complete a sale. Is the formula I suggested appropriate in that case? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry.. im not quite understanding what you mean? This whole extended thread of comments has ended up kind of convoluted from the initially asked question. As far as if the formula is appropriate.. best thing you can do is test it and see! As per my earlier comment though.. do not use utm_source=checkout. Do not use utm parameters.. use some other type of query string eg error=checkout or smething that makes sense to you for your reporting needs.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Apologies, yes agree that what I am asking has deviated alot from my initial question. However, you came across as so knowledgeable I figured I should clarify with you other queries I had. Thank you once again for helping me out.